# How can I align an image with css

Tags: html, css, image, layout

I have this code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTDgS/)

```
<div id="picture1">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/    3780/9455263123_9150ae4a6e_o.png" /></a>
</div>


<div id="picture2">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/   5483/9458043690_5bce524ccf_o.png" /></a>
</div>
```

and css

```
    #picture1        {
     top:-10px;
   left: 190px;
   right: auto;
    float:right;
}

 #picture2        {
     top:-10px;
   left: 50px;
   right: auto;
    float:left;
}

img {
    position:relative;
    top:-10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;

}
```

I  want the images to stay side by side, overlapping. Like this web site [example](http://www.chitarrastudio.com/)

How can i do this? I want to insert images and place them as they are designed in the background.

For now this is a simple background image, and I have to insert the two guitars with transition effects, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You already asked this question didn't you? EDIT: nevermind, You're stuck on a new problem for the same site :)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't match your question.

Comment: There are numerous images on the site you referenence, none of which help describe your requirements. A diagram would be helpful.

Comment: Ye sorry!! i'm not able to use this site xD i don't understend it completely. i try to delete the other question.

Comment: Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/jTDgS/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use positioning and z-index controls such as these:

```
#pic {
z-index:100;
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}
#pic2 {
z-index:999;
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:100px;
}
```

By applying these ID's to two seperate images you can get there desired results, but it will mess with your transistions and you'll need PNG's for it too look good.

Comment: Although this works, I would suggest against using absolute positioning for what you want.  Float the images instead.  See my answer and jsFiddle.

Comment: @hungerstar your answer should have been accepted to be honest, floating would cause far less hassle and it's something I completely overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to `float` the images.  This is how the site you linked to is doing it.

*HTML*

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city/" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city/" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city/" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city/" />
```

*CSS*

```css
img {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HCQLF/

The example above provides the most basic of usage.  You might need a containing element for all of your images and may need insert them into something like an un-ordered list.